# Suppress link (or just the color) of a specific \nameref

Tags: hyperref, color

The links that I'm creating with the `hyperref` package (e.g., references to other sections/chapter) are all coming out with a color that I've defined. That's as intended and it's working fine.

But I need to suppress the color of a specific reference. One that was created with `\nameref`. I just need the text of the referred section to be included. I don't want it to be colored differently. Any way to achieve this?

If, instead, there's a way to turn the named reference into ordinary text (i.e., also remove the link) it would be ok too.

Comment: It would be really great if you could help us out a bit. Create a small document that we can use to play around with. Helping us helps you, really.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Package `hyperref` provides star forms of the referencing commands to get the reference without the link (and link color):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \section{Hello World}
  \label{hello}
  Name reference with link: \nameref{hello}\\
  Name reference without link: \nameref*{hello}\\
  Reference with link and without color:
    {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\nameref{hello}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]